# PDO update, no errors and no respons in DB

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to update a specifik row in a table with no success or error message. I $_POST a form with many different inputs including one for selecting the specifik row(clubId).

I $_POST and use both name and value from my inputs in the form, handling these in the code below to make a query.

However, as I do not get any errormessage or can see anything wrong with my code except the security against injections I do not know where to proceed with this.

Do you see anything wrong with the code that could cause this? Otherwise, how should I proceed, tips, directions, new working code with the ability to handle forms without having to make any bigger change in the php code(Like I am trying below).

```
<?php 

include ('../../db_conn.php');

$nameArrayValue = array();

foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    if($name == 'clubId') {} else {
        $nameArrayValue[] = $name." = :".$name;
    }
}
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$values = implode(', ', $nameArrayValue);

$sql = "UPDATE random SET ".$values." WHERE id = :clubId";
$addRandom = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
        $name = ":".$name;
        $addRandom->bindParam($name, $value);
}

$addRandom->execute();

if($addRandom->rowCount() > 0) { echo' yaay'; }           

//header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

?>
```

Comment: What's in `$_POST['clubId']`? Can you build the query manually (that's easy to do with few adjustments in the code), then run it against the DB manually?

Comment: in `$_POST['clubId']` there is a number, for example 103, that will represent the row ID in DB.

Ok, I'll do that to look after errors.

Comment: Ok, now I know what went wrong. Thanks for the guidance into right direction.

There where two errors in the code:
`$addRandom->bindParam(:clubId, 199);` I had to switch the **:** into quotes around clubId and then change my value into a variable.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this question as resolved. To do that here, please add a self-answer below, and click the tick mark when the system lets you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There where two errors in the code:

`$addRandom->bindParam(:clubId, 199);`

I had to remove the : before clubId and then change my value into a variable like below:

`$addRandom->bindParam(clubId, $_POST['clubId']);`

And now my code looks like:

```
include ('../../db_conn.php');

$nameArrayValue = array();

foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    if($name == 'clubId') {} else {
        if(!empty($value)) {
            $nameArrayValue[] = $name." = :".$name;     
        }
    }
}

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$names = implode(', ', $nameArray);
$values = implode(', ', $nameArrayValue);

$sql = "UPDATE random SET ".$values." WHERE id = :clubId";
$addRandom = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    if(!empty($value)) {
        $addRandom->bindParam($name, $_POST[$name]);
        $name = '';
    }
}


$addRandom->execute();

if($addRandom->rowCount() > 0) { echo 'yaay'; }
```

Comment: You are using parameterisation for your `WHERE` values, but have injected column names/values into your query, and they don't seem to be escaped. This therefore looks like it has a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: The first parameter in the first two code samples is presumably a string, and thus is would need quoting in each case.